# VB.Net StartInfo.Arguments not working

Tags: vb.net, parameters, arguments

So ive been trying to use VB.Net to open a program with parameters, it works fine when i use a shortcut but i just cant get it to work with VB.Net i think it has something to do with a parameter like this "--user=test".

Heres the arguments and ive already tried using String.Format()

```
    Dim CMD As New Process
    CMD.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\test.exe"
    CMD.StartInfo.Arguments = "--user=test --pass=test -o test -p 1025 -d0 --verbose -f 60"
    CMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    CMD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    CMD.Start()
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please post the complete code to the part of your program that isn't working, along with what happens when it doesn't work.

Comment: All parts of the other code is fine, because when i try one parameter it works, its when i try all of those it doesnt.. and when i run the program a empty CMD window appears instead of one displaying Data

Comment: I have added the full code just in case

Comment: Remove the two statements that assign RedirectStandardXxx and try again.  Weirdo option style btw with both two dashes and one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, retval will be the output from the commands echo's to the console. I presume you want to capture this as you're redirecting std out:

```
Dim CMD As New Process
CMD.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\test.exe"
CMD.StartInfo.Arguments = "--user=test --pass=test -o test -p 1025 -d0 --verbose -f 60"
CMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
CMD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
CMD.Start()

Dim retval As String = CMD.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

CMD.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your process like this:

```
Dim myProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
```

not like:

```
Dim myProcess As New Process()
```

It will work.